# How find a parent process(whose ppid=1) of several worker processes on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I need to find process id of master process for say nginx applications. If I run

`$ ps aux | grep nginx | awk {'print $2'}`

I get following output.

```
599
3261
3264
27671
```

Out of which `3261` is master process whose **PPID** is `1`. How to find such process id?

Answer (score 1):

If your version of ps supprts it try:

```
ps --ppid 1 | grep nginx | awk {'print $1'}
```